# Bitlocker: Windows 10 does not offer to encrypt SSD drives

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, bitlocker

I encounter the phenomenon on Windows 10 that it does not offer to encrypt some of my SSD drives.
I also have drive d:\ and e:, but they are not listed on the BitLocker drive encryption setttings page in Windows.
Does anybody have had the same problem or know what's the problem is?
Sytem partition drive c:\ is also a SSD drive. All conventional drives work!

Regards

[image: System BitLocker settings]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management

Comment: @Daniel B. it's in German. Hope this is not a big problem.

Comment: d:\ and e:\ are primary partitions!

Comment: So basically all partitions that BitLocker doesn’t show are on MBR drives.

Comment: On my traditional hard drives with discs Bitlocker is available. My idea is, that, it has something to do with Samsung drive encryption?!? They are all Samsung SSDs!

Comment: USB-sticks work too!